# Limit of functions measurable with respect to sub-sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence, measurable-functions

Let $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ be a net of functions in a measure space $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$. Suppose that each $f_{\alpha}$ is measurable with respect to a sub $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$, and that the net has a limit, $f$, in the weak-* topology of $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$: that is, there is a $\mathcal F$-measuable function $f$ so that
$$\int f_{\alpha} \phi d\mu \to  \int f \phi d\mu$$
for every $\phi\in L^1(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$). Is $f$ $\mathcal G$-measurable?

Comment: My guess is not in general: If $\mathcal{G}$ is the Borel sigma algebra, and $\mathcal{F}$ the Lebesgue one; both in $\mathbb{R}$ say, then pick your favorite set $A$ that's Lebesgue but not Borel, then pick your net to be indexed by some points needed to make $A$ Borel measurable. We can guarantee that these will have the same measure and so the weak-* convergence follows, but the limit is not Borel.

Comment: I don’t quite understand. What do you mean that we pick out net to be indexed by some points needed to make A hotel measurable?

Comment: @Jose27 I tried to follow your outline, but one thing got me confused: Every Lebesgue-measurable function is almost everywhere equal to a Borel-measurable function. Thus, if $\mathcal{G}$ is the Borel-algebra and $\mathcal{F}$ the Lebesgue one, essentially every $\mathcal{F}$ function is equal to a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function. But then how do I tell if the limit $f$ is $\mathcal{G}$ or $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Comment: The net is indexed by sets under inclusion as your relation. Say $f_C(x)=1_C(x)$ where $C$ is any set such that $A\subset C\subset B$ and $B$ is Borel with the same measure as $A$.

Comment: @bs_math: That's the thing, you can run this argument whenever $\mathcal{G}$ is not complete (your "essentially" is the key; I agree they are, but as far as the sigma algebras go they don't; we're adding stuff in that the Borel sigma algebra doesn't know how to handle, even if *we* know after the fact that it's a negligible set). Of course you could ask that both sigma algebras have the same null sets, but as it's written the answer is no.